# execute a window application from linux using Python

Tags: linux, windows, batch-file, cmd, paramiko

I'm trying to run a batch file on a windows server. The batch file contains the following code:
"rtmserver 7 5".

which actually runs on windows:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Video Clarity\RTMonitor>rtmserver 7 5
```

i.e., it opens cmd and runs this command that starts the windows application properly

in the same way:
If I double click the batch file it opens THIS software that I can use it.
Id I drag and drop it to cmd it runs also OK (C:\Users\user>C:\Users\user\Desktop\ClarityCommands\RTMServer.bat.lnk)

**BUT, If I try to open it from SSH connection that is run on other Linux machine that uses paramiko and connects to this windows, It fails:**

```
class SSH_Connection(object):
    def __init__(self, LOCAL_IP, username, password):
        self.LOCAL_IP = LOCAL_IP
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        self.client.connect(self.LOCAL_IP, username=self.username, password=self.password)
        self.sftp = self.client.open_sftp()
    def std(self, message):
        self.message = message
        _in, out, err = self.client.exec_command(self.message)
        exitcode = out.channel.recv_exit_status()
        stdout = ''.join(out.read())
        stderr = ''.join(err.read())
        return stdout, stderr, exitcode

class Clarity(SSH_Connection):
     pass

clarity = Clarity(LOCAL_IP='172.24.11.57', username='user', password='user')
```

NOW, when I'm trying to call the batch file to execute the opening for this application by the following paramiko and SFTP options given by Python:

```
clarity.std('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Video Clarity\RTMonitor\RTMServer.bat"')
```

This returns the following:

```
('\r\nuser@CV-S2042-RTM C:\\Users\\user>rtmserver 7 5 \r\n',
 "'rtmserver' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n",
 1)
```

So, my Linux machine fails to open this application remotly

Any thoughts how to solve this?

Comment: So a path to `rtmserver` is in `PATH` environment variable of your local Windows account?

Comment: Are you logging into SSH using the same account as you use locally on Windows?

Comment: You may need to specify a fully qualified path to the `rtmserver.bat` script. If that is not enough, using `cmd.exe /C "C:\Program Files (x86)\Video Clarity\RTMonitor>rtmserver" 7 5` may be needed.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just execute rtmserver directly instead of putting it in a batch file?

Comment: @Squashman, how?

Comment: @lit, that doesn't work

Comment: Squashman means, that you can do `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Video Clarity\RTMonitor\rtmserver" 7 5`

Comment: @Itaybz - Sorry, I meant to say `cmd.exe /C "C:\Program Files (x86)\Video Clarity\RTMonitor\rtmserver.exe" 7 5`. This is if the `rtmserver.exe` file is in that directory. If not, change the directory.

Answer (score 0):

So, looking at your output:

> ('\r\nuser@CV-S2042-RTM C:\Users\user>rtmserver 7 5 \r\n',
>    "'rtmserver' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n",
>    1)

This appears that you are trying to run `rtmserver` from `C:\Users\user`

Unless the path to `rtmserver` exists in your `PATH` environment variable, the system will assume that the executable is in the current working directory (which is `C:\Users\user`)

Adding `C:\Program Files (x86)\Video Clarity\RTMonitor` to your `PATH` environment variable should fix this.

Comment: True. But OP claims that the batch file works, when executed locally. So I assume that the path to `rtmserver` must be present in `PATH` variable, at least **in some situations**.

Comment: Do you need quotes because of the spaces in pathname?

Comment: Normally a path in the `PATH` variable should not need quotes. They are separated with the `;` character rather than a space. I wonder if this may be a difference in whether it is defined in the user `PATH` or the system `PATH`. Is the batch being executed by the same user that can double-click-to-run?

Comment: @marti, the PATh variable is there:C:\program files (x86)\video clarity\RTMonitor